# Font changes in browser

Tags: css, fonts

http://yummylekker.be/test.gif

As you can see in the image on the link above, I have a problem with my fonts.
At some point it changes when I view it in a browser...can't seem to find out why or when.
I analysed both times with FontFinder and the font aswell as the values are the same.
Georgia is rendered in both cases.
It seems to affect every browser and every font.
Only way to have it change back to the original, correct one is to reboot my computer :s

Anyone has any idea what the reason might be?

```
#wrapper #about p, #wrapper #comingsoon p {
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 18px;
color: #414141;}
```

Same browser, same font, displays correctly at first but at some point when I view it again ( same browser etc ) it has changed ( FontFinder still says it's the same font, but it's displayed differently )

Comment: You should tag your question with whatever language / framework you are using, if you want to increase the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I think the question is: how come my fonts are different in a browser as compared to photoshop/illustrator/MS office

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear, the problem is: I open my browser ( any browser ) and my font looks oké, I open it 5 minutes later ( same browser, same font ) and it has changed, as you can see in the gif. Because of the change in font my layout changes too ( it's width is different )

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has it's own way of analysing and visualising fonts.
If you use standard fonts, you will have the best chance of every browser showing it correctly.

Furthermore, if you use webfonts or @font-faces, you have to know that not every font is made for web purposes and therefore the one shows **itself differently in a different browser.**

To add even more to the font problem, you have different services (like fontsquirrel) who can make your fonts into websafe fonts. **Different services = different results!**

This means that in case of your problem, you'll have to have all 3 or 4 major browsers open next to eachother and aks yourself if the font is good enough for you.

This is a very hard and time-consuming part of the job. http://www.google.com/webfonts are for me the best solution (for now)

Comment: Every type of font wich is not standard increases the loading/rendering time. And google webfonts are no exception, but the one thing you know is that when you use google webfont library, you know what you're getting and what you're sacrificing for it, whilst you go to a service like fontsquirrel, you need to tweak the font to make the file smaller and then manually look at the loading time it gives + you dont know how your font will look like untill you've uploaded it and tried it out yourself.

Comment: The font I'm using for the paragraph is Georgia. "font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;". And it displays fine at first, but after closing and opening the browser again at some point it changes...And I can't say it's a different font, just differently displayed? Can't seem to get an explenation.

Comment: It's like the gif is showing, it's the same browser, same website, nothing has changed, yet the font changes.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do dynamic (non-image) text rendering and expect consistent spacing.**

Here's one reason why.

The font has "hints" inside it, telling the rendering engine how best to display the text at small sizes. One of these images is not using the hints, the other is. Thus, I suspect you're seeing a fast "initial" version followed by a slower "refined" (hinted) version.

The details: in Georgia, the "b" should be taller than the "H", and the "a" has a lachrymose (teardrop) terminator. In your image A, the "b" is the correct height, but there's no teardrop on the "a". In image B the "b" has been shortened to match the "H", but the teardrop is present. I believe image B is the "refined" image.

To test this, try the same text with the font size much larger. I believe the re-rendering will not happen. Another thing you might try is to turn ClearType on and off.

I realize this doesn't solve your problem, but that's because this isn't a programming problem, it's a *design* problem. Again: **You cannot do dynamic (non-image) text rendering and expect consistent spacing.**

Many designers *hate* this, because they're stuck in ink-and-paper thinking. (Personally I find such people [tirade deleted].)